# python argparse array instead of str

Tags: python, argparse

I'm running into issues when using argparse. With below code, I expected 
args.dir to be a string, but instead I got an array. How can I get a string? Can anyone help?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import argparse

#import mysql.connector

# Set version number
version = '1.0.0'

# Parse arguments supplied on the commandline
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=sys.argv[0])
argparser.add_argument('dir', nargs=1, type=str, help='directory to view')
args = argparser.parse_args()

# Print program name and version number to stdout
print(argparser.prog + " v" + version)
print('Creating index for: ' + args.dir[0])
```

Comment: List, not an array.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs  *Note that nargs=1 produces a list of one item. This is different from the default, in which the item is produced by itself.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You indicated `nargs=1` and even though you provided the value 1, argparse built you a list (like an array but [not exactly the same thing](https://www.pythoncentral.io/the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array/)). This is actually helpful because you can guarantee that when you indicate `nargs`, you will always get a list.

Remove the `nargs` parameter and you will get a string rather than a list.

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks. Also thanks for providing some extra insight in array vs list.